# PyQGIS setSubsetOfFields function in QGIS 2.4

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2.4

I found the function setSubsetOfFields to filter fields in a layer in the PyGIS cookbook:

http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-a-subset-of-features

But it seems like that these function doesn't exist in QGIS 2.4. Neither has the layer a fields() function. There is only a setSubsetOfAttributes function.

I tried to use it like this:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()  
request = QgsFeatureRequest()
request.setSubsetOfFields(['id', 'name'], layer.fields())

features = layer.getFeatures(request)
for feature in features:
    print feature.attributes()
```

Am I using this wrong or is there another possibillitie to set a filter on the layer fields?

Comment: Use ```setSubsetOfAttributes(["id", "name"], layer.pendingFields())```. The PyQGIS Cookbook will be updated.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The attribute list I get looks like this `[7045, u'Berlin', None, None]`. Is there a possibility to get only a list of the two requested features?

Comment: There is a way in python: ```[attr for attr in feature.attributes() if attr is not None]```

Comment: Thanks. I iterate over the list of fields and use attribute with the field name `feature.attribute(field)`. Because if the attribute is a null value it will be not appended to the list.

Comment: Yeah, you also can get it by index from feature object like so: ```feature["field_name"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use this code to filter specific fields out of the layer attributes:

```
fields = ['id', 'name']
filterFields = []
features = layer.getFeatures()
for feature in features:
    attrs = [feature[field] for field in fields]
    filterFields.append(attrs)
```

This generates a list containing the filtered attributes for every feature of a layer.

Comment: You shouldn't do like that. By doing this, you are loosing performance as QGIS will fetch all attributes. Using QgsFeatureRequest, QGIS can reduce the amount of data returned by the query on the data provider side. It will take more time and memory.